# Combine multiple files from different folders and renamed as folder name to new folder by Python

Tags: python

I have many .txt files and store in different folders, I want to combine multiple files from different folders and renamed as folder name to new folder by python.

Structure as below :

Path xxx

Folder 1

- 1.txt
- 2.txt
- x.txt

Folder 2

- 1.txt
- 2.txt
- x.txt

Folder x

- 1.txt
- 2.txt
- x.txt

After combined and renamed, structure should as below :

New path

folder1.txt (combine 1.txt,2,txt,x.txt in folder1)

folder2.txt

folder3.txt

I have written codes as below to open different folderX.txt, but I get problem about write if to combine different files under same folder to new folderX.txt.

```
import os
path = "/Users/guozhao/Downloads/2021-02-04 10-12-07_NSGI/"

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    for dir in dirs:
        write_files = [os.path.join(dir) + '.txt']
        for wf in write_files:
            with open(wf,'w') as outfile:
                for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
                    for file in files:
                        read_files = os.path.join(root,file)
                        if os.path.isdir(read_files):
                            for rf in read_files:
                                with open(rf,'r') as infile:
                                    outfile.write(infile)
```

Comment: Welcome!  Please define the problem that you are having with this code.  If you are getting an error message, please supply the complete message in your question, including the full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see the error when I run the code. I can see the new folderX.txt under my folder, but nothing write in my new files.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have figured out this request :

```
import os
path = input('Please input your file path: ')

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    for dir in dirs:
        if dir == ".DS_Store":
            continue
        write_files = os.path.join(dir) + '.txt'
        with open(write_files,'w') as outfile:
            read_path = os.path.join(root,dir)+'/'
            for readfile in os.listdir(read_path):
                if readfile == ".DS_Store":
                    continue
                with open(os.path.join(read_path,readfile),'r') as infile:
                    infile_content=infile.read()
                    outfile.write(infile_content)
```